# Create two new Dataframes from existing one based on unique and repeated values of a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
colA colB
 A    125
 B    546
 C    4586
 D    547
 A    869
 B    789
 A    258
 E    123
```

I want to create two new dataframe and the first one should be based on the unique values in 'colA' and the second one should be the repeated values of 'colB'. The colB has no repeated values. The first output is like this:

```
ColA colB
 A   125
 B   546
 C   4586
 D   547
 E   123
```

The second output is like this:

```
colA colB
 A   869
 B   789
 A   258
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first group, use `drop_duplicates`. For second group, use `duplicated`:

```
print (df.drop_duplicates("colA"))

  colA  colB
0    A   125
1    B   546
2    C  4586
3    D   547
7    E   123

print (df[df.duplicated("colA")])

  colA  colB
4    A   869
5    B   789
6    A   258
```